# How to update most current state in class component

Tags: reactjs

I have a component with a `cursorIndex` that I've been refactoring from a functional component to a class component.

When it was a functional component, and I was using using the `useState` state hook, I could pass a function to `useState`, and it would update the most current `cursorIndex`. For example:

```js
// cursorIndex => 1

setCursorIndex(currentIndex => currentIndex + 1)
setCursorIndex(currentIndex => currentIndex + 1)

// cursorIndex => 3

// Even though the update is asynchronous, somehow React
// applies both of these increments and not just one. Great!
```

Now I have a class component. I wrote my own setter function so I could pass it to children:

```js
setCursorIndex(incrementor){
  this.setState({ 
    cursorIndex: incrementor(this.state.cursorIndex)
  })
}
```

Which works fine except the state it gets passed is not necessarily the most up-to-date state.

```
// cursorIndex => 1

setCursorIndex(currentIndex => currentIndex + 1)
setCursorIndex(currentIndex => currentIndex + 1)

// cursorIndex => 2
```

I'd like to keep the component a class component because I'd like to be able to easily reset all its state to default. Is there any way to get it to update current state the way useState does? Or, should I just keep it a functional component?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty clear in the docs:

```js
incrementCount() {
  this.setState((state) => {
    // Important: read `state` instead of `this.state` when updating.
    return {count: state.count + 1}
  });
}
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html

Well, despite feeling foolish, I guess I'll leave this up here in case it helps someone else.